# Shp to topojson WITH filtering in one command?

Tags: topojson

I usually see and use a first `ogr2ogr` comand to convert from `.shp` to `.geoJSON`. In a second command, I use `topojson.js` to convert from `.geoJSON` to `.topoJSON` format, with simplification of the precision, coordinates, arcs, and filtering to keep relevant metadata only. Example :

```
# DOWNLOAD: Data from http://gadm.org/
CRI_adm.zip:
    curl -o CRI_adm.zip http://gadm.org/data/shp/CRI_adm.zip

CRI_adm0.shp: CRI_adm.zip
    unzip CRI_adm.zip
    touch CRI_adm0.shp

# PROCESS DATA: SIMLIFY, FILTER
costarica.json: CRI_adm0.shp
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON costarica.json CRI_adm0.shp

# Require topojson: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson
# (this minifies/simplifies the data)
costarica_min_topo.json: costarica.json
    topojson \
        -p name=NAME \
        -p name \
        -q 1e4 \
        -o costarica_min_topo.json \
        costarica.json
```

But, since `topojson.js` can convert from `.shp` directly into `.topoJSON`, with simplification of the precision, coordinates, arcs, **can we jump `ogr2ogr` and directly convert *and filter* with a single `topojson.js` command ?** Such:

```
# PROCESS DATA: SIMLIFY, FILTER
    topojson \
        -p name=NAME \
        -p name \
        -q 1e4 \
        -o costarica_min_topo.json \
        CRI_adm0.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

ogr2ogr has a -where parameter. You can use -where "name=NAME" to filter the features of the shp file